# Could not find compatible versions for gem "spree_core"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I've just ran through the 'Getting Started' guide from Spree commerce and I've hit an error while following it.

I've run the following commands:

```
gem install spree_cmd
bundle install
```

Then I get hit with the following errors in the console

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spree_core":
  In Gemfile:
    spree_auth_devise (~> 3.0.0) was resolved to 3.0.5, which depends on
      spree_core (~> 3.0.0)

    spree (~> 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
      spree_backend (= 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
        spree_core (= 3.1.0)

    spree (~> 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
      spree_backend (= 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
        spree_core (= 3.1.0)

    spree (~> 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
      spree_backend (= 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
        spree_core (= 3.1.0)

    spree (~> 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
      spree_backend (= 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
        spree_core (= 3.1.0)

    spree (~> 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
      spree_backend (= 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
        spree_core (= 3.1.0)
```

Which looks like it all checks out - but it seems to be failing to bundle install.

**My Gemfile**

```
gem 'spree', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.0.0'
```

Any help would be brilliant

Comment: Try deleting `Gemfile.lock` and doing `bundle install` again.

Comment: Didn't work :( still comes up with the same errors as above

Answer (score 1):

You same versions for all 3 extensions/gems.
Either, (for Spree 3.1.x)

```
gem 'spree', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.1.0'
```

Or, (for Spree 3.0.x)

```
gem 'spree', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.0.0'
```